# Varnish seems to not be using my `file` storage configuration

Tags: varnish

I've configured Varnish to use a file storage. Varnish seems to be working, but the cache seems to be a fraction of the size I've specified and the file I've specified for the storage does not seem to have been created.

I've been running `service varnish reload` to restart the service after making config changes. Is that sufficient?

Running `varnishstat` shows an ever-increasing `MAIN.n_lru_nuked` value, which I assume means it thinks it's run out of cache space however `SMA.s0.c_bytes` (which I believe is the size of the storage back-end?) is only at `3.46G`.

Any ideas how I can debug this? Is my config not getting picked up?

### Config portion of /etc/default/varnish

```
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -b s3.amazonaws.com:80 \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s disk=file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,30G"
```

### /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "cdn.webampskins.org.s3.amazonaws.com";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.Host = "cdn.webampskins.org.s3.amazonaws.com";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 3y;
    set beresp.storage_hint = "disk";
    # I've confirmed that in my response I see this header
    set beresp.http.x-storate = "disk";

}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Empty
}
```

### Update:

It seems that my file storage config is not getting picked up:

```
~# varnishadm storage.list
Storage devices:
    storage.s0 = malloc
    storage.Transient = malloc
```

Not sure why, or how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system uses *Systemd*, don't use `/etc/default/varnish` to configure the runtime parameters.

Please use the following command to edit these settings:

```
sudo systemctl edit varnish
```

Once you're done editing, restart Varnish using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart varnish
```

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/quick-start/#through-the-systemctl-edit-command for more information about managing Varnish via the `systemctl` binary.

> Word of warning: we strongly discourage the use of the `file` stevedore. Although it allows you to extend the size of your cache compared to memory, it does not offer any persistence. That might be something you can live with.
>
> However, our experience with the `file` stevedore is that it is very prone to disk fragmentation over time. The only way to get rid of the fragmentation is by fully restarting the `varnishd` process via `sudo systemctl restart varnish` on a regular basis.